# SQL query in Java (WHERE)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select all rows that have "helloworld" in "category" column. Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM `commands` WHERE `category` = `helloworld`
```

I get this error:

```
Unknown column 'helloworld' in 'where clause'
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to have '' fields that are non - variables. Just try this ;

`SELECT * FROM commands WHERE category = "helloworld"`

Answer (score 4):

Try with

```
SELECT * FROM `commands` WHERE `category` = 'helloworld'
```

instead. Note the ' around helloworld instead of `

Answer (score 0):

That should be

```
SELECT * FROM `commands` WHERE `category` = 'helloworld'
```

Note the difference in quotes. Strings are quoted with ' while table/column names can optionally be quoted with ` to avoid being interpreted as keywords.